# LinQ to SQL : Update on table data not working

Tags: sql, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a LinQ query which is intended to Update the table concerned.

The code is as follows:

```
LINQHelperDataContext PersonalDetails = new LINQHelperDataContext();
var PerDetails1 = (from details in PersonalDetails.W_Details_Ts
                         where details.UserId == userId 
                         select details).First();
PerDetails1.Side = "Bridge";
PerDetails1.TotalBudget = 4000000;
PersonalDetails.SubmitChanges();
```

However, this change/update does not get reflected in the DB. Also,this does not throw any exception.Please suggest.

Comment: 1. Do these values actually modify the properties? 2. Check the executed SQL statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure W_Details_Ts has one (or more) member properties marked as primary key. L2S can't generate update or delete statements if it does not know the underlying table's PK member(s).

Comment: This actually solves my problem. I marked one of its members as the Primary Key, and the update worked. But is there any reason why L2S behaves in this way? I mean, why is it necessary to have a Primary Key ?

Comment: Because if L2S does not know the key, it can't generate the where predicate for update or delete statements.

update [table] set [column] = somevalue where [key] = keyvalue